# Hibernate One to Many relation- Child table not updating

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Here I am adding a list of new orders to a specific user. While adding orders to a specific user, it returns success status, but still my database is empty. Why the data is not getting added...?

**Users**

```
@Entity
Class Users{

@Id
private int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Orders> orders;

}
```

**Orders**

```
@Entity
Class Orders{

 @Id
 private int id;

 private Date orderDate;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;
}
```

**Repository**

```
public ResponseEntity<String> addOrder(int userId,List<Orders> orders) throws UserNotFound{
        User user =userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        if(user==null) throw new UserNotFound("User Not Found");
        for(Orders o:orders){
            o.setOrderDate(new Date("....."));
        }
        user.getOrders().addAll(orders);
       userRepository.save(user);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to add cascade persist to your relation specification:

```
@Entity
Class Users{

@Id
private int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Orders> orders;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Orders entity have no reference to the parent entity. Thats the reason save Users have no impact on orders.

Try to add users(parent entity references) to each elements of orders list.